# Who makes a better nucleophile? CH3O- or OH-?

Tags: nucleophilicity

My argument is that the +I effect of CH3 group increases the electron density at oxygen atom, making it a better nucleophile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is methoxide a better nucleophile than hydroxide?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35068/is-methoxide-a-better-nucleophile-than-hydroxide)

Answer (score 0):

When the donor atom is same, a general rule applies: nucleophilicity parallels basicity. Thus, comparing the basic strength of methoxide and hydroxide, it is observed that  methoxide is a stronger base than hydroxide (as it the conjugate base of a weaker acid i.e. methanol when compared to water). Thus, methoxide is a stronger nucleophile than hydroxide.

[However, at the same time NMR data predicts that methanol is a stronger acid than water (despite the I+ effect of $\ce{-CH3}$ group)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42535/is-methanol-more-acidic-than-water). So, in this case, there exists a controversy.